# Rating bar setRating

Tags: android, android-activity, ratingbar, rate

I am working on an android project and I got this rating bar on which the user can rate and after rating the `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` is called and everything is fine.

But when the activity loads again I need the application to get the rate of the rater on the rated page and it is fine till now. When I get float number from database I should then call the `ratingbar.setRate(1.5)` but when I do this the app also calls the `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` and I don't want the application to call any method just set the rate because the user already rated but also if the user wanted to change his rate it is fine I want the app to call `setOnRatingBarChangeListener` and it does call.

What should I do?

Comment: Post your code as well, It will help in getting to know what you are doing !

Answer (score 1):

A little trick:

Before setting rating, remove the listener. Then set the rating and set the listener again.

Try something like this:

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(null);
ratingBar.setRating(1.5f);
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(/*listener*/);
```